# Uncaught CredisException

Tags: magento2

I face following issue:

> Uncaught CredisException: Connection to Redis 127.0.0.1:6380 failed

after 2 failures.Last Error :

> 111) Connection refused

Does anyone know to solve it ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check your app/etc/env.php , if it is setup correctly . 
Test redis:

```
redis-cli ping
```

Check if is being loaded:

```
php -m | grep redis
```

Comment: command? not working it was working before stop sudden

Comment: see if you made any modification to your env.php , check if you are able to mysql , and test the commands i sent you.